# Is there a way I can install matlab support on Raspbian through command line and access it through matlab?

Tags: raspbian, matlab

Instead of going through the elaborate procedure mentioned [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/raspberrypiio/ug/install-support-for-raspberry-pi-hardware.html).

Can't I install any support package through commands like `sudo apt-get install` on Raspberry Pi? I already have the support package in matlab for Raspberry Pi on my system. What changes do I need to make on that? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this through `apt-get`.

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9V4Xcxlc9Q) that walks you through it. Enjoy the awkward cadence :)

Comment: Hey that's the same method that I have mentioned in the question and I want to avoid that, since the raspbian image that comes along with the package doesnt allow me to connect to internet.

Comment: Or else, can you tell me how I connect to the internet when I follow the steps in that video? I can't connect my pi to internet after I get the raspbian through matlab

Answer (score 0):

You could install GNU Octave [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) which is a MATLAB clone

```
apt-get install octave
```